# How to set String format in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift2

I have TextField in my application, after entering value in textField i am checking textformat in following delegate method

`func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)`

I want to check like following,

if textField Containing "23" then output should be "23.00"

if textField Containing "23.1" then output should be "23.10"

if textField Containing "23.10" then output should be "23.10"

any idea for this

Comment: what then, if it contains "2A3" , ".1" , "2310" etc ?

Comment: NO it  doesn't contains value like that, because i have already restrict value for that textfield

Comment: keyboard is decimal point keyboard, so only number and . (dot) allows

Comment: and another restriction that i have put is only 1 decimal point allows so there is no any chance for second decimal point

Comment: for the case "2310" ?

Comment: it should be 2310.00

Comment: for the case "23." and "23.023" ?

Comment: just add 00 after .(dot) so it should be 23.00

Comment: 23.023 is not possible value bacause i have restricted value. only two digits are allows after decimal point

Comment: i have also tried following code

let b = 2.0
print(String(format: "%.2f", b))

but if value of b = 2 then it will not giving me desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that the text is restricted to a numeric value I recommend `NumberFormatter`

```
let text = "23"

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
let formattedString = numberFormatter.string(from: Double(text)! as NSNumber)
```

Sorry the code is Swift 3 code. It's highly recommended to update, consider that Swift 4 is waiting in the wings.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Working perfectly

Comment: It was a very simple solution you gave me but i was just stuck in different condition matching and all.
Thanks

Comment: great answer @vadian

Answer (score 1):

(**Swift 3**) It works good for the cases "23" , "23.1" , "23.10" .

```
func process(_ input : String ) -> String
    {
        var string = input
        if !string.contains(".")
        {
            string += ".00"
        }
        else
        {
            for (index,char) in input.characters.enumerated()
            {
                if char == "."
                {
                    if index == input.characters.count - 1
                    {
                        string += "00"
                    }
                    else if index == input.characters.count - 2
                    {
                        string += "0"
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return string
    }
```

I hope can you handle issues between **Swift 3** and **Swift 2.3**